# Need to access the MULTIPLE (possible) Selected Options

Tags: listbox, dart, dart-polymer

I have constructed a "listBox" in HTML using select & option tags and for single selections
all is working as expected inside the respective PolymerElement.

However, when I enable **mutiple** options with the Multiple=true attribute turned on 
then only the expected values of the **top most** selectIndex and value are passed to me in the option_selected() "Lifecycle" method.

I have found multiple solutions involving JQuery and JS, but nothing I have tried has worked with
Dart-Polymer.  (The straight JS solution I found will not successfully access variables.)

The HTML/Polymer code (inside a  tag) looks like this:

```
    <select  multiple=true style="width:250px;" selectedIndex="{{selected}}" value="{{value}}" size="8" on-click="{{option_selected}}" on-change="{{on_change}}" >           
       <option template repeat="{{dataEle in dataAr}}" > {{dataEle}} </option>
    </select>
```

The preferred solution would be Dart or Polymer-Dart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the selected values this way:

```dart
@observable var values = toObservable(<String>[]);


void on_change(event, details, Element target) {
  var el = (shadowRoot.querySelector('select') as SelectElement);

  var v = <String>[];
  el.options.forEach((o) => o.selected ? v.add(o.value) : null);
  values.clear();
  values.addAll(v);
}
```

Just to show the selected values on the page

```dart
<template repeat="v in values">
  {{v}}
</template>
```

Comment: Worked right out of the box!  Danke! I will say, however, that I find it a little 'awkward/surprising' that a really 'meat and potatoes' HTML problem like this requires digging down to the shadowRoot (at this point). (I thought I was missing some sort of obvious HTML 'trick' for hours, and I have tried to avoid the ShadowDom because so many changes are taking place. However, I see that this is powerful window for all kinds of custom work...)

Comment: As soon as you have a Polymer element you have a shadowDOM. `shadowRoot` is just the context of `querySelector`. `document.querySelector` searches the document `shadowRoot.querySelector` searches inside the custom element.  If the tag has an `id` attribute you can just use `$['theid'];` (without `#`) instead of `shadowRoot.querySelector('#theid');

Comment: Understood.  I will add only an aside: when I went to Dart API to list the methods of the ShadowRoot for studying I ended up looking at the pageSource and was completely dazzled that it is written in Polymer, a great place to see this stuff working, and I see now that the front-page of Dart is also.  Very interesting! I wonder for how long?

Comment: That changed very recently (in the last 3 weeks I think)